# Which is a good strategy to read a formatted excel file in java to put it latter in a JSON format?

Tags: java, json, excel, apache-poi

I need to think about a strategy to read data stored in an excel sheet formatted so that it can be delivered in JSON format, as long as they keep original headings.

But since the headers are complex that is my biggest problem; how to handle them, I can't think of a good strategy to put them as expected in the output. here is the real excel file I need to decompose: https://github.com/EEsparaquia/readFormattedExcel/blob/master/Book1.xlsx

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Order002                    |       |                             | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
02X Phones                  |       |                             |
                                    -------------------------------
                            |       |   Order condition           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                            |       |                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
order | Date | Group | Desc | Comm- | Order | Type | Sub Condition|
  #   |      |       |      |  ents | Type  |      |--------------|
      |      |       |      |       |       |      | Blue  |  Red |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |12119 |   A   | 5.9  |  New  |  D40  |  2   |   90  |   2  |
      |      |       | Inch |       |       |      |       |      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  2   |12119 |   A   | 5.9  |  New  |  D40  |  2   |   87  |   3  |
      |      |       | Inch |       |       |      |       |      |
```

---

And my output should be in JSON format:

```
{
 "Order002":{
   "02X Phones":{
     "Order #":"1",
     "Date":"12119",
     "Group":"A",
     "Desc":"5.9 Inch",
     "Comments":"New",
     "Order Conditions":{
      "Order Type":"D40",
      "Type":"2",
      "Sub Condition":{
       "Blue":"90",
       "Red":"2"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

So far I am able to read the excel sheet data line by line and column by column, that is, first I read cell [1, A], [1, B], [1, C] ... [1, "n"] and after [2, A], [2, B], [2, C] ... [2, "n"].

Here is my code so far:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class App {

   public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "Book1.xlsx";

   public static void main(String []args){

    try {
        //Creating a workbook from Excel file
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        //Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        DataFormatter dataFormatter= new DataFormatter();

        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Java 8 forEach with lambda\n");

        sheet.forEach(row -> {
            row.forEach(cell -> {
                printCellValue(cell);

            });
            System.out.println("End of forEach - Lambda");
         });


        workbook.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void printCellValue(Cell cell){
    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()){
        case BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case STRING:
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
                System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
            else
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        case BLANK:
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("\t");
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would recommend not nesting your output Json and just having a simple object with a bunch of key-value pairs.  The excel spreadsheet didn't need to have so much nesting of headers and could have been made a lot simpler

Comment: I wish I could have less headers from excel, but the thing is, since those excel files come from a legacy system, I can not do much about it, so I need to maintain the same structure, that is the reason I need to nested the values in JSON, just to preserve the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions about the file (since I don't have access to more than the very small part of the file you provided).  I'm going to assume that there are no other header rows that appear in the file after you reach the first row of real data.  If my assumption is wrong, you can provide some more of the file maybe?

Here is some high level psuedocode:

```
public Json parseExcel(Excel excel){
  List<List<String>> rows = excel.readRows();
  Json json = Json.array();
  int startingIndex = 4; //skip header rows
  for(int i = startingIndex; i <= rows.size(); i++){
    List<String> row = rows.get(i);
    json.add(Json.object()
        .with("orderNum", row.get(0))
        .with("date", row.get(1))
        //... all the other columns ...
        .with("subCondition", Json.object()
            .with("blue", row.get(7))
            .with("red", row.get(8)));
        );
  }
  return json;
}
```

Comment: You are right with your assumption, I couldn't upload the actual excel file or even a picture to show how it looks like. I see you get all the data from the file, but here is the thing, How can you link the data with their corresponding header, in order to have the first levels into the format, meaning "Order002" and "02X Phones" respectively? You think is a good strategy handle the headers in a separate object?

Comment: sorry buddy, can't really help more without seeing the file

Comment: Fair enought, I recently create this repo to work with, here is the file I need to decompose: (https://github.com/EEsparaquia/readFormattedExcel/blob/master/Book1.xlsx)

Comment: I know, but as this sheet are many and sometimes have more data